# preventing emails from entering junk mail

Tags: php, html, email, html-email, spam

so I'm sending people emails using PHP's mail() command but it ends up in their junk folders...

I know that the junk mail filters the subject/body of the email for fishy title/body, but what are some guidelines in composing my subject/body such that they don't get sent to junk mail?

Currently here are my subject/body

subject:

```
New object request
```

body:

```
<p>A new object request has been submitted</p>
<p>Object Info</p>
<ul>
  <li>Category: Cat</li>
  <li>Object Name: Legitimate Object</li>
  <li>Street Address: Legitimate Address</li>
  <li>City: Awesome City</li>
  <li>State/Country: Country</li>
  <li>ZIP/Postal Code: 10001</li>
  <li>Website: </li>
  <li>Comment: </li>
</ul>
<p>User Info</p>
<ul>
  <li>Name: vjaklfjsd2795 cvkljasdfl</li>
  <li>Email: vlkafjlsdf@sdafsaf.com31784</li>
  <li>UID: 48482</li>
</ul>
```

using php's mail() and the message got moved to the junk folder...what's wrong with my message and what can I do to improve it?

Comment: Are you including any specific header to your email?

Comment: Where are you sending your emails from? Your own server? Shared hosting? Dedicated hosting?

Comment: Just do not write junk emails!

Answer (score 3):

The inner workings of spam filters is a closely guarded secret - if spammers knew what not to do, they could get around the spam filters.

However, the body of your mail seems to avoid the obvious signs - you're not offering to enlarge anything, or make us rich.

Here are some links:

- http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-spam-filters-think - mostly about the words to avoid.
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques (and especially http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques#PTR.2Freverse_DNS_checks - given the content of your mail, I think it's more likely a DNS thing)
- http://www.emaildeliveryjedi.com/dns-configuration.php - more on the DNS thing